# xquery copy text values from one element to another

Tags: xml, xquery, transformation

How would I achieve copying text values from one element in xml doc to another.

**source**

```
 <f> <a> val1 </a> <b> val2 </B> </f>
```

**target**

```
 <G> <alpha/> <beta/> </G>
```

**desired result**

```
 <G> <alpha>val1</alpha> <beta>val2</beta> </G>
```

Tried doing it with below

```
let $src:= f/*
let $tgt:= G/*

**Option1 :** Let src/text():= tgt/text() // does not work 
**Option2:** 
 for $i in $src let $tgt[$i/position()]/text() := $i/text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change an element in normal XQuery (although there exists an extension "XQuery update"). Especially not with `let` as it is only used to set variables.

But you can create a new element with the same name and content:

```
let $src:= f/*
let $tgt:= G/*
for $s at $i in $src 
return element { name($tgt[$i]) } { $s/node() }
```

Comment: thks much, appreciate it. Did not know for can take at operator as well.